# Can't Link Psapi.h in Open Source Project Using MinGW

Tags: c, linker, makefile, mingw, configure

I am trying to modify the source code to an open source application on windows that uses mingw.

I am having a problem linking the psapi library.

psapi.h and libpsapi.a are in the mingw directory and I have tested it using the standard

`gcc -o program program.c -lpsapi`

method, and it works.

However, when I try to compile the program using the

```
./configure
make
```

method, it doesn't work I have tried,

```
./configure LDFLAGS=-lpsapi
make
```

and that doesn't work

and I tried going into the makefile.am and putting -lpsapi in AM_LDFLAGS but that doesn't work

The error it gives is just a standard "undefined reference to [function]", implying that the library with the functions is not linked

I have even tried putting psapi.h in the source directory and including it as `#include "psapi.h"` and that STILL didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

LDFLAGS is the wrong one.
LIBS=-lpsapi should do the trick.

The order is important for the linker. The libraries (LIBS) have to come after the objects, LDFLAGS can be before.